# Pandas, Apply function return wrong results

Tags: python, pandas

I've this issue with this function, which must return the proportion of each feature in one column.

Here's some data much easy to make up an idea:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['A', 'A', 'B' , 'C'], 'Y': [1, 0, 0 , 1], 'Z': [1, 0, 1 , 1]})

df2['X'].value_counts()
```

When I count the values I get

```
A    2
B    1
C    1
```

Now, I need to get the proportion for each value of "X"

```
for freq in df2['X'].value_counts():
    #print(freq)
    print(freq/df2['X'].value_counts().sum())
```

The result below :

```
0.5
0.25
0.25
```

Perfect,

Now I must apply to my Dataframe and get a new column.
Below the function:

```
def get_proportion(df):
    for freq in df2['X'].value_counts():
        return (freq/df2['X'].value_counts().sum())

df2["A"]=df2.apply(get_proportion, axis=1)
```

result:

```
    X   Y   Z   A
0   A   1   1   0.5
1   A   0   0   0.5
2   B   0   1   0.5
3   C   1   1   0.5
```

I should get

```
    X   Y   Z   A
0   A   1   1   0.5
1   A   0   0   0.5
2   B   0   1   0.25
3   C   1   1   0.25
```

What's  wrong ?

If I set an argument

```
df2["A"]=df2.apply(get_proportion(df2), axis=1)
```

I get an error

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Thank you if you can help.

Comment: Think about what your function is doing. Your for-loop **always returns on the first iteration**. Also think of the signature, `de get_proportion(df)`, you never *use the argument*, and the name implies you think that it would be a dataframe, which it wouldn't be anyway...

Comment: I agree, but  when I set the "return" under "for ... " I get Ident error

Comment: Without argument the function return error TypeError: get_proportion() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Yes... again, *what did you think it was going to do?* It requires an argument, and if you are going to use `.appy` it will use the argument. I'm trying to lead you to understanding... have you read the documentation for `.apply`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2["A"] = df2.X.apply(lambda x: (df2["X"].value_counts() / len(df2))[x])
```

---

- `len(df2)` is number of rows of the dataframe `df2`,
- `(df2["X"].value_counts() / len(df2))` is a series with relative occurences of elements in the column `"X"`.

Comment: I test it, I get the "Nan" in df2["A"], please chek

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho, you were right, sorry, I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do (to fix the first attempt):

```py
dftemp=df2['X'].value_counts(normalize=True)
df2=df2.set_index("X")
df2["A"]=dftemp
df2=df2.reset_index()
```

The reason why your attempt doesn't work is because `pandas` does index-based auto-fitting during assignment i.e.

`df1['x']=df2['y']`

Won't assign `df2` values in order, but only there where `df1` index matches `df2` index regardless of order, and regardless whether there are repeated indexes, or not.

As an alternative you can `merge` them and do a simple join by `X`.